# Yii use of Component and behaviour

Tags: php, yii, components, behavior

How Could I make generalised function which  are used by every Model and Controllers Using Component as well behaviour??

Comment: could you give an example of what this functionality is as well as what you've tried so far?

Comment: Component [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13280-how-to-create-hello-world-component/page__view__findpost__p__65116)

Answer (score 0):

```
//your behavior    
class TestBehavior extends CActiveRecordBehavior
    {
        public $a = '';
        public $b = '';

        public function getA(){
            return $this->a;    
        }

        public function getB(){
            return $this->b;
        }    
        ... 
    }

//in your model
public function behaviors(){
        return array(
            'TestBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'TestBehavior',
                'a' => 'value a ',
                'b' => 'value b',
            ),
            //one more behavior
        );
    }
...
// use model behavior:
echo $model->TestBehavior->getA();

// in controller you can use attachBehavior() it will be like:
$this->attachBehavior('TestBehavior', array(
      'class' => 'TestBehavior',
));
```

Hope this help you.